# Aligning geom_text to geom_jitter points

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I align (along the x axis dimension) the text labels with the jittered points in the following plot in R `ggplot2`?

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
mtcars %>% 
    ggplot(aes(am, wt, group = am, label = wt)) +
    geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA) +
    geom_jitter() +
    geom_text()
```

[image]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Easy solution would be to specify `position_jitter` in both `geom_text` and `geom_jitter` with the same `seed`.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(am, wt, group = am, label = wt)) +
    geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA) +
    geom_jitter(position = position_jitter(seed = 1)) +
    geom_text(position = position_jitter(seed = 1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

And if we want to **avoid that the numbers overlap the points**, we can do:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(am, wt, group = am, label = wt)) +
  geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA) +
  geom_jitter(position = position_jitter(seed = 1)) +
  ggrepel::geom_text_repel(position = position_jitter(seed = 1)) # Note edit here
```

Output:
[image]