# How to align geom_repel_text to geom_jitter points when subsetting the data?

Tags: r

I am making boxplots and jitter to show each individual point. I am then putting text labels on each point. This works fine but as soon as I try to subset which points I want label, the text doesn't align any longer.

Here is my code (with some help from this page):
[Aligning geom_text to geom_jitter points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52317280/aligning-geom-text-to-geom-jitter-points)

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(vs, wt, group = am, label = wt)) +
  geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA) +
  geom_jitter(position = position_jitter(seed = 1)) +
  geom_text_repel(data = subset(mtcars, wt > 3),
                  position = position_jitter(seed = 1))
```

Here is my plot. As you can see the labels are not aligned with the points.
[image: boxplot with jitter and subsetted labels]

Any ideas why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that by subsetting `ggrepel` will only see this part of your data and assumes that your are only plotting the subset. If you want `ggrepel` to take account of all your data use an `ifelse` condition to select the points you want to label instead of subsetting:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(vs, wt, group = am, label = wt)) +
  geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA) +
  geom_jitter(position = position_jitter(seed = 1)) +
  geom_text_repel(aes(label = ifelse(wt > 3, wt, "")), position = position_jitter(seed = 1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is to use a custom alpha to make the weights you don't want to display invisible:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(within(mtcars, visible <- wt > 3),
       aes(vs, wt, group = am, label = wt)) +
  geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA) +
  geom_jitter(position = position_jitter(seed = 1)) +
  geom_text_repel(position = position_jitter(seed = 1),
                  aes(alpha = visible)) +
  scale_alpha_manual(values = c(0, 1)) +
  guides(alpha = guide_none())
```

[image]